# I phone 4 start up not loading (previously jailbroken)

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone, jailbreak

I have an old IPhone 4, jailbroken. When I was in cydia I deleted some elements to run the Iphone (I was young and naive, didn't have a clue what I was doing)

From this the Iphone wont turn on, tried putting it in back up mode, manually resetting, and tried to get it back to I Tunes to update it to a newer version of IOS to get the program files back, but was unable to access itunes with the device. The screen just has a low battery symbol and will not move from that.

Anyone have any help, would be much obliged.

James

Answer (score 1):

You won't have bricked the phone. At most, the software will be corrupt. You'll be able to fix this. Do the following:

1. Leave the phone to charge overnight, to try and get off the low battery symbol. Try to use a wall adapter rather than the USB port on your computer, as the wall will provide more power.
2. Connect the phone to your computer.
3. Enter DFU mode: Hold the power button for three seconds. Then, hold the home and power buttons for ten seconds. Then, release the power button and keep holding the home button until the device appears in iTunes. In DFU mode, the screen will be completely black.
4. Restore the iPhone as usual.

Comment: *as usual* means, connect it via USB with iTunes ;)